# Restricting my endpoints with API Key in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm using cloud endpoints v2 for java. My problem is that anyone can access these endpoints method through **API Explorer** or from directly **URL** someone know. I want to protect my endpoints. I read documentation how to restrict Whole API or some methods by using **API KEY**. [Restricting API Access with API Keys](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys-frameworks)

Here is what I'm trying.

```
@Api(
        name = "zeem",
        version = "v1"
)

public class Account {
@ApiMethod(name = "getRegistration", path = "getRegistration", apiKeyRequired = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
public Registered getRegistration(@Named("phone") Long phone){
  // code ....
}
```

I can run this method without any API key and it is working successfully.
Even I try it to access this method directly from url its also working.

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/zeem/v1/getRegistration?phone=123 // Successfully getting response
```

Can you please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Is there any thing I miss ?

**Update- OpenAPI Doc**

Yes I'm adding **API management** Here how `openapi.json` look like for this function.

```
    "/zeem/v1/getRegistration": {
   "get": {
    "operationId": "ZeemGetRegistration",
    "parameters": [
     {
      "name": "phone",
      "in": "query",
      "required": true,
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "int64"
     }
    ],
    "responses": {
     "200": {
      "description": "A successful response",
      "schema": {
       "$ref": "#/definitions/Registered"
      }
     }
    },
    "security": [
     {
      "api_key": [ ]
     }
    ]
   }
  },
```

Here is how console look like.

[image]

What I'm missing ?

**Update: Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- [START_EXCLUDE] -->
<!--
  Copyright 2016 Google Inc.
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at
        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- [END_EXCLUDE] -->
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- OBJECTIFY -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <!-- ENDPOINTS -->
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.octabyte.zeem.API.Account,
                org.octabyte.zeem.API.CommentApi,
                org.octabyte.zeem.API.FriendApi,
                org.octabyte.zeem.API.ListApi,
                org.octabyte.zeem.API.PostApi,
                org.octabyte.zeem.API.SearchApi,
                org.octabyte.zeem.API.UserApi,
                org.octabyte.zeem.API.StoryApi
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Route API method requests to the backend. -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Security -->
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you first [add API management](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management)?

Comment: Yes, I add it please check update

Comment: Please post your `web.xml` as well.

Comment: Yes, I add it please check the update

Answer (score 0):

There's a misunderstanding on what the API key access restriction is. The [API key restriction](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys-frameworks) is to restrict what APIs the key has access to, it does not in any shape or form deal with authentication of users.

There are a few ways to authenticate your users for Endpoints, for example, you could use [API management](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management) or you could look into using [OpenAPI](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users).

Comment: Yes I add **API Management and OpenAPI Doc** Please check the update. But still I'm able to access endpoint method without any api key

Comment: I am a bit confused about what you want, so I will give you both options. If you are concerned that unauthenticated users can access your Endpoints, you need [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users); if you are concerned that your endpoint might randomly be hit by the internet (protect the Endpoint from random anon unintended traffic), then you will need to [block all access without API Key](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys-openapi#restricting_access_to_all_api_methods).

Comment: I want the second option. But as you can see in my question I'm trying this but it's not working. I want to know why it's not working. What I'm missing ?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. So you have one API method restricted by project API key (some random internet traffic can't access it).

Have you tried actually deploying it that testing it in production (maybe to a test version)? Also, you can hit the URL, but does it return meaningful data (like does it let you actually run the code)?

If so, then it seems like an issue that you can report to our [issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) so we can investigate into it from our end, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I tried it on actual deployment. Same issue. I posted the issue right here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113347216

Comment: I will take over the issue and make sure it gets handled.

Comment: Can you please look at my issue